# get subdirectory relative URL from relative URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, subdirectory, url.action

We have an MVC4 application,

there is a navigation panel at left side of the screen and this navigation tree is built dynamically along with additional parameters.

so we store the navigation Url in a column in a table (say `/Dataset/Financial`).

now when application is hosted on a subdirectory(say `http://localhost/xyzabcd/`) the Url generated dynamically from the table still targets the root(ie., `http://localhost/Dataset/Financial`).

I got to know that `Url.Action()` will actually solve the problem.

Now since it has been designed like that, I would like to know if there is any standard way I can get the fully qualified URL for a relative URL(so that we don't have to make any change in the db)? Is there any built-in or existing method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the scheme/protocol, it should give you the FQDN that you're looking for.

Example

```
Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { routeData = 1}, "http")
```

Note, that routeData I just put in as a placeholder.  You could set that to `null` if desired.   Also, "http" could also be "https"

Comment: I don't have Action and Controller names separately.. I have `Controller/Action`..

Comment: I would split those out, either in the database or through string manipulation.  Otherwise there's not really much point in using `Url.Action()`

Comment: I am aware of `Url.Action()`, I want to know is there any other way?